# How to trace a SQL trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, trace

I'd like to trace the execution of a trigger but I don't know really how to do it. With the autotrace set on, the first idea that came to my mind was force the trigger but it still doesn't work.
**How am I supposed to view the execution tracer of a trigger?**

Comment: What kind of tree information are you looking for? Can you just run it in the PL/SQL debugger? The SQL\*Plus [`SET AUTOTRACE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/tuning-SQL-Plus.html) report is for SQL execution plans and resource usage statistics, not for debugging triggers.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle gives you two good ways to trace PL/SQL.  The preferred way is using the DBMS_HPROF package.  Less good (it's older) is DBMS_PROFILER.

Since DBMS_PROFILER is simpler and your requirements are simple, I'll demonstrate that.

First, let's create a table with a trigger on it:

```
CREATE TABLE matt_test1 ( a number );

CREATE TRIGGER matt_trg1 BEFORE INSERT ON matt_test1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;
```

Next, we start the profiler, run an `INSERT` (which should fire our trigger), and then stop the profiler:

```
EXEC DBMS_PROFILER.START_PROFILER;

INSERT INTO matt_test1 (a) values (1);

EXEC DBMS_PROFILER.STOP_PROFILER;
```

Now, there are better ways to start and stop the profiler.  Those ways will return the run ID that was used, which you will need in order to query the results.  In our quick-and-dirty example, we will just look the most recent profiler results that are out there:

```
SELECT * FROM plsql_profiler_runs order by runid desc;
```

On my system, that was `runid` 2.

Next, we query the `PLSQL_PROFILER*` tables to get all the information about PL/SQL that was executed during the run.  This won't list just triggers -- it'll be a lot more: pretty much any SQL statement called from PL/SQL and pretty much any other PL/SQL block (procedure or function) called from PL/SQL.

Here is the query I used to use for this (before I switched to using `DBMS_HPROF` for this:

```
SELECT   d.runid,
         u.unit_type,
         u.unit_owner,
         u.unit_name,
         d.line#,
         d.total_occur,
         d.total_time / POWER (10, 9) total_seconds,
         d.min_time / POWER (10, 9) min_seconds,
         d.max_time / POWER (10, 9) max_seconds,
         ss.source line_text,
         SUM (d.total_time / POWER (10, 9)) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL ORDER BY d.total_time DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
                                                                                                               cumulative_seconds,
         SUM (d.total_time / POWER (10, 9)) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL) elapsed_seconds_for_run
FROM     plsql_profiler_data d INNER JOIN plsql_profiler_units u ON u.runid = d.runid
         AND                                                       u.unit_number = d.unit_number
         LEFT JOIN SYS.user$ su ON su.NAME = u.unit_owner
         LEFT JOIN SYS.obj$ so
         ON  so.NAME = u.unit_name
         AND so.owner# = su.user#
         AND DECODE (so.type#,
                     7, 'PROCEDURE',
                     8, 'FUNCTION',
                     9, 'PACKAGE',
                     11, 'PACKAGE BODY',
                     12, 'TRIGGER',
                     13, 'TYPE',
                     14, 'TYPE BODY',
                     'UNDEFINED') = u.unit_type
         LEFT JOIN SYS.source$ ss ON ss.obj# = so.obj#
         AND                        ss.line = d.line#
WHERE    1=1
and d.runid = 2
AND      d.total_occur > 0
ORDER BY d.total_time DESC;
```

Finally, the results:

```
+-------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-------+-------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+--------------------+-------------------------+
| RUNID |    UNIT_TYPE    | UNIT_OWNER  |  UNIT_NAME  | LINE# | TOTAL_OCCUR | TOTAL_SECONDS | MIN_SECONDS | MAX_SECONDS | LINE_TEXT | CUMULATIVE_SECONDS | ELAPSED_SECONDS_FOR_RUN |
+-------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-------+-------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+--------------------+-------------------------+
|     2 | ANONYMOUS BLOCK | <anonymous> | <anonymous> |     1 |           2 |   0.000010001 |    0.000001 | 0.000008001 |           |        0.000010001 |             0.000013001 |
|     2 | TRIGGER         | APPS        | MATT_TRG1   |     2 |           1 |      0.000002 |    0.000002 |    0.000002 | BEGIN     |        0.000012001 |             0.000013001 |
|     2 | ANONYMOUS BLOCK | <anonymous> | <anonymous> |     1 |           1 |      0.000001 |    0.000001 |    0.000001 |           |        0.000013001 |             0.000013001 |
+-------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-------+-------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+--------------------+-------------------------+
```

You can see our trigger being fired in row #2, above.

Answer (score 1):

Two way come to mind:

If you can change the trigger code, create a log table and write debug messages to it from the trigger body:

```
CREATE TABLE trigger_log (t TIMESTAMP, m VARCHAR2(4000));

CREATE OR REPLACE my_trigger BEFORE INSERT ...
BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO trigger_log(t, m)
  VALUES (systimestamp,'my_trigger fired :new_id is='||:new_id);

  ... rest of trigger body ...
END;
/
```

Secondly, if you can change the audit settings, switch on audit for the relevant table.

Comment: I usually include an "ID" column (populated by a sequence) in the log table. Sometimes things happen very fast and many rows share the same timestamp value, so I'm not sure which one happened first.

Comment: It is often a good idea to place auditing statements, like your `INSERT INTO trigger_log...` in an autonomous transaction block.  That way, if the work is rolled back, you still keep a log of what executed.  Actually, it's probably one of the few legitimate use cases for `PRAGMA autonomous_transaction;`